# Receive Ethernet packets in Linux with several Ethtypes in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, ethernet

I want to receive ethernet packets from socket in Linux, but only those, which have one of two custom Ethtype values.
As I know, if only 1 ethtype should be received, it's possible to specify this value while creating socket like this

```
int socket = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETHERTYPE_CUSTOM_1);
```

But what if I have 2 different ethtypes? Should I use 2 sockets or write some custom filter? Or is there some any simple way?

Comment: I'd use 2 sockets, that way your code won't run for every packet the system receives, just to filter out most of them.

Comment: You could also consider using one socket set up to capture everything and then installing a BPF program. Indeed, I would just use libpcap and utilize the `pcap_setfilter` function which, on linux, knows how to install BPF into the kernel. The `link` directive should allow you to specify the appropriate field in the link header on which to do the comparison.

Comment: @Barmar please add you comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two sockets, one for each ethertype. Then you can use `select()` or `epoll()` to wait for packets on either socket at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use libpcap library. You need to access bpf packer filter.
This is easy one.
Or you can use iptables rules an netfilter library. You need to set prerouting iptables rules to forward all packet to specific port and your application binding this port as listening mode and you can receive full packet.